# preventing overlong forms when parsing UTF-8

Tags: unicode, utf-8

I have been working on another UTF-8 parser as a personal exercise, and while my implementation works quite well, and it rejects most malformed sequences (replacing them with U+FFFD), I can't seem to figure out how to implement rejection of overlong forms. Could anyone tell me how to do so?

Pseudocode:

```
let w = 0, // the number of continuation bytes pending
    c = 0, // the currently being constructed codepoint
    b,     // the current byte from the source stream
    valid(c) = (
        (c < 0x110000) &&
        ((c & 0xFFFFF800) != 0xD800) &&
        ((c < 0xFDD0) || (c > 0xFDEF)) &&
        ((c & 0xFFFE) != 0xFFFE))
for each b:
    if b < 0x80:
        if w > 0: // premature ending to multi-byte sequence
            append U+FFFD to output string
            w = 0
        append U+b to output string
    else if b < 0xc0:
        if w == 0: // unwanted continuation byte
            append U+FFFD to output string
        else:
            c |= (b & 0x3f) << (--w * 6)
            if w == 0: // done
                if valid(c):
                    append U+c to output string
    else if b < 0xfe:
        if w > 0: // premature ending to multi-byte sequence
            append U+FFFD to output string
        w = (b < 0xe0) ? 1 :
            (b < 0xf0) ? 2 :
            (b < 0xf8) ? 3 :
            (b < 0xfc) ? 4 : 5;
        c = (b & ((1 << (6 - w)) - 1)) << (w * 6); // ugly monstrosity
    else:
        append U+FFFD to output string
if w > 0: // end of stream and we're still waiting for continuation bytes
    append U+FFFD to output string
```

Comment: How do you handle surrogate pairs encoded as separate UTF-8 sequences?

Comment: Do you mean, how do I handle `c = [0xd800..0xdfff]`? I reject them by way of `valid(c)` returning false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you save the number of bytes you'll need (so you save a second copy of the initial value of `w`), you can compare the UTF32 value of the codepoint (I think you are calling it `c`) with the number of bytes that were used to encode it. You know that:

```
U+0000 - U+007F 1 byte
U+0080 - U+07FF 2 bytes
U+0800 - U+FFFF 3 bytes
U+10000 - U+1FFFFF 4 bytes
U+200000 - U+3FFFFFF 5 bytes
U+4000000 - U+7FFFFFFF 6 bytes
```

(and I hope I have done the right math on the left column! Hex math isn't my strong point :-) )

Just as a sidenote: I think there are some logic errors/formatting errors. `if b < 0x80 if w > 0` what happens if w = 0? (so for example if you are decoding `A`)? And shouldn't you reset `c` when you find an illegal codepoint?

Comment: For the sidenotes: the first was my mistake when converting my C code to pseudocode. I've fixed that up now; thanks for the heads up. I'm not sure if resetting `c` is necessary, though, because `c` is assigned to when a sequence-starting byte is encountered.

Comment: @Delan You are right NOW :-) (with the revised version of the code :-) :-) ) BUT you should put an else before `append U+b to output string` and `w = (b < 0xe0) ? 1 :`

Comment: I don't think so. When you prematurely end a multi-byte sequence with an ASCII byte, we should add an U+FFFD, but shouldn't drop the ASCII character, which is what would happen if I inserted an `else`.

Comment: By the way, while UTF-8 is defined up to U+7FFFFFFF, unicode itself is only defined up to U+10FFFF and that is encoded with 4 bytes. So no point bothering with the 5 and 6 byte sequences.

Comment: Good point. For simplicity and consistency, I don't check for the start 5 and 6 byte sequences and reject them off the bat, but rather parse them normally and reject them (i.e., append U+FFFD) at the end when the codepoint fails the validity check.

Comment: @Jan Right. I was fooled by the Wiki UTF-8 "Design" table :-)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the decoded character, you can tell how many bytes it should have had if properly encoded just by looking at the highest bit set.

If the highest set bit's position is <= 7, the UTF-8 encoding requires 1 octet.
If the highest set bit's position is <= 11, the UTF-8 encoding requires 2 octets.
If the highest set bit's position is <= 16, the UTF-8 encoding requires 3 octets.
etc.

If you save the original `w` and compare it to these values, you'll be able to tell if the encoding was proper or overlong.

Answer (score 1):

I had initially thought that if at any point in time after decoding a byte, `w > 0 && c == 0`, you have an overlong form. However, it's more complicated than that as Jan pointed out. The simplest answer is probably to have a table like [xanatos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399828/preventing-overlong-forms-when-parsing-utf-8/7399922#7399922) has, only rejecting anything longer than 4 bytes:

```
if c < 0x80 && len > 1 ||
   c < 0x800 && len > 2 ||
   c < 0x10000 && len > 3 ||
   len > 4:
 append U+FFFD to output string
```

Comment: **WRONG**. Totally, absolutely and catastrophically! The codepoint U+0800 (first with 12 bits) does not fit in 2 bytes, but coded in 3 bytes it will be 0xe0 0xa0 0x80 and the first byte has all the value bits 0, so after decoding it you have w=2, c=0 and it's **NOT** an overlong sequence! Similar case for codepoints with 17 and 18 bits.

Comment: I see. This is not the way to go then.